# Updating WooCommerce products by php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, product

I have an e-commerce store made with WooCommerce. In my store I have implemented a plugin, which allow users to subscribe to prices of specific products. This plugin informs the user only about a price change via email, when I manually change the price and save the product. This works perfect.

So far so good, the only problem is that I don´t change the prices manually, because they´re generated automatically by another plugin.

My goal is now to just save every product of my store every hour by a php-script and a cronjob. How to set up a cronjob is not the problem, but I don´t know the php-script.

All in all the php-script only has to be able to go into every product and just save it.

Because I´m new to WordPress and PHP, I don´t have any clue.

Thank you very much for helping out!

Comment: You need to trigger that email?

Comment: Yes that´s it .